# How to rename object name from gcloud Bucket via C# code?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I want to rename objects name from Google Cloud Bucket using C# code.
How can I do that?

Comment: You can't change object names from external API, but you can wrap object with yours

Answer (score 2):

GCP Support here!

You can actually rename an existing object using C#. As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#storage-rename-object-csharp) to do it you can use this code:

```
private void MoveObject(string bucketName, string sourceObjectName,
    string destObjectName)
{
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    storage.CopyObject(bucketName, sourceObjectName, bucketName,
        destObjectName);
    storage.DeleteObject(bucketName, sourceObjectName);
    Console.WriteLine($"Moved {sourceObjectName} to {destObjectName}.");
}
```

You'll see that what this code does is first copying the object with the new name, and then delete the old named object.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) you can find more information on how to use client libraries such as for C# and other environments.